# Where is QtCreator resource alias?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

The QtCreator resource editor has had a major change since the version 3.1. The new version shows resource files in project tree which i think is a good idea because most operations can now be done without opening the editor.

But it seems that something is missing here. The previous versions had an "Alias" field in the properties section for a resource file. I can not find such a thing in QtCreator 3.1.

Is this feature gone in the new versions and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Right click** the `.qrc` file and select `Open in Editor`

Answer (score 3):

When I open my resource file in the editor in version 3.1.0, the alias is still there: -

[image]

Comment: But i can not see this window. This window was in the previous versions. In the newest version you can just view resource structure and files in the project tree. Also you can add prefixes by right clicking the resource in the project tree.

Comment: So your question should have been "how do I open the resource file in the editor?" I assumed, when you mentioned the 'properties section' that you could open the editor. As you can see in the image it is labelled 'Properties'.

Comment: Well, at least you got there in the end.